# sql get balance at end of year

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum, date-arithmetic

I have a transactions table for a **single year** with the amount indicating the debit transaction if the value is negative or credit transaction values are positive.

Now in a given month if the number of debit records is less than 3 or if the sum of debits for a month is less than 100 then I want to charge a fee of 5.

I want to build and sql query for this in postgre:

```
select sum(amount), count(1), date_part('month', date) as month from transactions where amount < 0 group by month;
```

I am able get records per month level, I am stuck on how to proceed further and get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by generating the series of month with `generate_series()`. Then join that with an aggregate query on transactions, and finally implement the business logic in the outer query:

```
select sum(t.balance) 
    - 5 * count(*) filter(where coalesce(t.cnt, 0) < 3 or coalesce(t.debit, 0) < 100) as balance
from generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-12-01', '1 month') as d(dt)
left join (
    select date_trunc('month', date) as dt, count(*) cnt, sum(amount) as balance,
        sum(-amount) filter(where amount < 0) as debit
    from transactions t 
    group by date_trunc('month', date)
) t on t.dt = d.dt
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e23cc618604b9c95605f590a79d0b735)**:

```
| balance |
| ------: |
|    2746 |
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach?

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN usage.amount_s > 100
        OR usage.event_c > 3
        THEN 0 
      ELSE 5
    END
  ) AS YEAR_FEE
FROM (SELECT 1 AS month UNION
      SELECT 2 UNION
      SELECT 3 UNION
      SELECT 4 UNION
      SELECT 5 UNION
      SELECT 6 UNION
      SELECT 7 UNION
      SELECT 8 UNION
      SELECT 9 UNION
      SELECT 10 UNION
      SELECT 11 UNION
      SELECT 12
) months
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
  SELECT 
    sum(amount) AS amount_s,
    count(1) event_c,
    date_part('month', date) AS month
  FROM transactions
  WHERE amount < 0
  GROUP BY month
) usage ON months.month = usage.month;
```

Comment: In my case, the year is fixed. I have records for only 1 year. Here , I have 12 months in a year, so I have to consider all months also. But this query is considering on the records present in the given table. I mean, in my table I have records only for Jan, March, Oct. But the fee should be applicable to Feb, Apr, May, Jun, Jul etc.

Comment: Added the part for the missing months. (not fond about the explicit year month mapping but it works. See (here)[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3e0bf/8])

Answer (score 1):

First you must use a resultset that returns all the months (1-12) and join it with a `LEFT` join to your table.
Then aggregate to get the the sum of each month's amount and with conditional aggregation subtract 5 from the months that meet your conditions.
Finally use `SUM()` window function to sum the result of each month:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(
         COALESCE(SUM(t.Amount), 0) -
         CASE 
           WHEN SUM((t.Amount < 0)::int) < 3 
             OR SUM(CASE WHEN t.Amount < 0 THEN -t.Amount ELSE 0 END) < 100 THEN 5 
           ELSE 0  
         END
       ) OVER () total
FROM generate_series(1, 12, 1) m(month) LEFT JOIN transactions t 
ON m.month = date_part('month', t.date) AND date_part('year', t.date) = 2020
GROUP BY m.month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6c62649eb792b5f2ce5f40c8b383094f).
Results:

```
> | total |
> | ----: |
> |  2746 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the hanving clause.

```
Select ( sum(a.total) - (12- count(b.cnt ))*5 ) as result From  
(Select sum(amount) as total , 'A' as name from  transactions  ) as a  left join  
(Select  count(amount) as cnt  , 'A' as name
From transactions 
where amount <0 
group by month(date) 
having not(count(amount) <3 or  sum(amount) >-100) ) as b 
on a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score -1):

select
sum(amount) - 5*(12-(
select count(*)
from(select month, count(amount),sum(amount)
from transactions
where amount<0
group by month
having Count(amount)>=3 And Sum(amount)<=-100))) as balance

from transactions  ;

Comment: I think this will help u out to solve this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33505606)